# Could not locate executable f95, f77, xlf, ifc, g77

Tags: python, macos, numpy, setup.py

I'm trying to install glmnet using [these instructions](https://github.com/dwf/glmnet-python). When I run `python setup.py` and I choose the interactive option to build, I get the following `Could not locate executable XXX` errors. I've installed scipy and numpy via pip.

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "glmnet._glmnet" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize NAGFCompiler
Could not locate executable f95
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
customize IBMFCompiler
Could not locate executable xlf90
Could not locate executable xlf
customize IntelFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
running scons
--Return--
> /Users/rose/221/tagger/tagger/glmnet-python/setup.py(32)<module>()->None
```

Comment: bit it looks like it found `gfortran` and is trying to use it.  Are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: More important: what _is_ the actual problem you're facing? If you're just seeing scary stuff in the logs but everything works… there aren't any errors there, so you're fine. If something is breaking later on, tell us what's breaking. (You might also want to tell us what platform you're on, and the versions of Python/gfortran/scipy/etc. And where you got the Python—came with your OS, installed from Python.org, built it manually, installed with package manager X, …)

Comment: This is the actual problem I'm facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459390/python-glmnet-no-module-named-glmnet. I'm running mac OS, I compiled the Python myself about a week ago, I think with the huge features option. My versions of scipy and numpy are the latest, and I also just installed gfortran.

Comment: What more information can I provide?

Comment: Is this the full printout of what `setup.py` prints out? I'm not sure the "Could not locate"s are really errors, as it's unlikely that this package would require you to have 5 different fortran compilers installed.

Comment: Do you have `f2py` installed?

Comment: No, I don't have `f2py` installed.

Comment: I think you need `f2py` to install `.pyf` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Could not locate`s aren't really errors. It's unlikely that a package would require you to have 5 different fortran compilers installed.